# R replacing missing values with na.locf

Tags: r, data.table, time-series, missing-data, zoo

I am new to R. I was hoping to replace the missing values for X in the data. How can I replace the missing values of "X" when "Time" = 1 and 2 with the value of "X" when "Time" = 3 for the same "ID" and the same "Day"

X: only has a valid value when Time is 3, others are missing.

```
 ID   Day  Time   X    
 1    1     1     NA
 1    1     2     NA
 1    1     3     7.4
 1    2     1     NA
 1    2     3     6.2
 2    1     1     NA
 2    1     2     NA
 2    1     3     7.1
 2    2     3     5.9
 2    2     2     NA
 2    2     1     NA
```

I was able to write and run the following codes with the package zoo and data.table, but afterward when I checked the data, it didn't work--the X value still has all the missing values when time=1 and 2. Anything wrong with my code? Any suggestions? I have very limited experience in R. Thank you in advance!

`setDT(data1) 
data1 <- data1 [order(-Time),
              X := na.locf(X),
              by = .(ID, Day)]`

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 options:

1) Using rolling join in `data.table`:

```
DT[, X1 :=
    DT[!is.na(X)][.SD, on=.(ID, Day, Time), roll=-Inf, x.X]
]
```

2) using `data.table::nafill` with "locf" by ID and Day after sorting by ID, Day and descending Time:

```
DT[order(ID, Day, -Time), X2 := nafill(X, "locf"), .(ID, Day)]
```

output:

```
    ID Day Time   X  X1  X2
 1:  1   1    1  NA 7.4 7.4
 2:  1   1    2  NA 7.4 7.4
 3:  1   1    3 7.4 7.4 7.4
 4:  1   2    1  NA 6.2 6.2
 5:  1   2    3 6.2 6.2 6.2
 6:  2   1    1  NA 7.1 7.1
 7:  2   1    2  NA 7.1 7.1
 8:  2   1    3 7.1 7.1 7.1
 9:  2   2    3 5.9 5.9 5.9
10:  2   2    2  NA 5.9 5.9
11:  2   2    1  NA 5.9 5.9
12:  2   3    1  NA  NA  NA
13:  2   3    2  NA  NA  NA
14:  2   3    3  NA  NA  NA
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("ID   Day  Time   X    
1    1     1     NA
1    1     2     NA
1    1     3     7.4
1    2     1     NA
1    2     3     6.2
2    1     1     NA
2    1     2     NA
2    1     3     7.1
2    2     3     5.9
2    2     2     NA
2    2     1     NA
2 3 1 NA
2 3 2 NA
2 3 3 NA")
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, some of the Time == 4 also have missing values. In that case, will the first option work better?

Comment: @Susan can you post an example? if there is always a latter time with a value, either option will work by backfilling those earlier time with the first available value

Comment: I am not sure how to post an example, but I will dry my best to describe one.       When the Time == 3, some of X have missing values as NA. In that case, I am okay with all of the values of X when Time == 1 and Time == 2 are replaced by NA.

Comment: @Susan, i added the example for you. Can you see if the interpretation is correct?

Comment: Can I ask what is `DT`? Thank you!

Comment: `DT` is the data.table in the section under data

Answer (score 1):

We can use `replace` :

```
setDT(data1)
data1[, X := replace(X, is.na(X), X[Time == 3]), .(ID, Day)]

#    ID Day Time   X
# 1:  1   1    1 7.4
# 2:  1   1    2 7.4
# 3:  1   1    3 7.4
# 4:  1   2    1 6.2
# 5:  1   2    3 6.2
# 6:  2   1    1 7.1
# 7:  2   1    2 7.1
# 8:  2   1    3 7.1
# 9:  2   2    3 5.9
#10:  2   2    2 5.9
#11:  2   2    1 5.9
```

Similarly using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
data1 %>% group_by(ID, Day) %>% mutate(X =replace(X, is.na(X), X[Time == 3]))
```

---

If you have more than 1 value in a group where `Time == 3` use `which.max`

```
data1[, X := replace(X, is.na(X), X[which.max(Time == 3)]), .(ID, Day)]
```

When there is no value for `Time == 3` we can use :

```
data1[, X := if(any(Time == 3)) replace(X, is.na(X), X[which.max(Time == 3)]), .(ID, Day)]
```

Comment: Thanks! Why it showed "Error in x[list] <- values : replacement has length zero" when I used the code "setDT(data1)
data1[, X := replace(X, is.na(X), X[Time == 3]), .(ID, Day)]"

Comment: Probably, there are certain groups where there is no `Time == 3`.

Comment: Indeed, when the Time == 4 some of X have missing values. How to solve it in this case?

Comment: What do you want as expected output when there is no `Time ==3` in the group? Keep `NA` as `NA` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Keep NA as NA when X == NA when Time == 3. Sorry for the typo "4" in the previous reply--that is probably very confusing!

Comment: When I used this code `X := if(any(Time == 3)) replace(X, is.na(X), X[which.max(Time == 3)]), .(ID, Day)]` the error message showed `Error in .(ID, Day) : could not find function "."`

Comment: Have you copied the answer correctly? `data1[, X := if(any(Time == 3)) replace(X, is.na(X), X[which.max(Time == 3)]), .(ID, Day)]` works fine for me without any error. I assume you have ran `setDT(data1)` earlier.

Answer (score 1):

In the example in the question each group has at most one non-missing value and in every case that value is to be assigned to every value in that group so if that is the general case the rule reduces to assigning the single non-NA value to all X values in the group:

```
data1[, X := na.omit(X), .(ID, Day)]
```